# Выпадающий список с инпутом и чекбоксом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать выпадающий список с инпутом.
Может есть какой-нибудь плагин.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Вот такой пример выпадающий список с инпутом с помощью [`datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist):

```html
<input type="text" name="example" list="lst">
<datalist id="lst">
  <option value="One">
  <option value="Two">
</datalist>
```

Пример использования `CheckBox` внутри списка:

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select>
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="one">
        <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
      <label for="two">
        <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
      <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Ссылка на источник ответа: [How to use Checkbox inside Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547021/5275890)

И немного модифицированный код из примера, получился CheckBox и инпутом внутри списка:

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 300px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 300px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select>
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="one">
        <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First<input type="text" id="oneText" /></label>
      <label for="two">
        <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second<input type="text" id="twoText" /></label>
      <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third<input type="text" id="threeText" /></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Немного поработать со стилями, навести красоту и получится как у Вас на картинке. Вообще, можно посмотреть на стили в [`Bootstrap`](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/), там достаточно красивые выпадающие списки.